# Can't check user login or email and password SQL

Tags: php, sql

I want to let my user to login via email or login.

My data are email/password or login/password only and must recognize that.

Here's the SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ( login = :login OR email = :email ) AND password = :password
```

Looks fine for me but when I want to use that in my method:

```
public function login(){
    require("db.php");
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ( login = :login OR email = :email ) AND password = :password');
    $stmt->bindParam(":login",$this->login);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email",$this->login);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password",$this->password);
    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); // RETURN false
}
```

It doesn't work, data are correct for sure.
What's wrong with that?

EDIT:
This query works (without brackets) but not properly of course:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = :login OR email = :email AND password = :password
enter code here
```

Comment: Perhaps you have stored a hash for the password field but you are querying with password's plain text string?

Comment: No, password is hashed in $this->password. I think problem can be with brackets query without them works.

Comment: What function are you using to hash you password? If you're using `password_hash`, you can't just hash your password again (because it generates a new hash), you have to use `password_verify`. Which means you should selecting the password hash in your query, but not using it as part of the where clause.

Comment: I'm using md5() from PHP and not hashing it twice, I do this in my constructor.

Comment: I would recommend you try the query without the email/login part and see if it succeeds: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = :password`

Comment: I checked that, works. Look at my edit

Comment: In you edit you have two conditions: (1) `login = :login`, or (2)  `email = :email AND password = :password`. If there is a problem with your password, you cannot know with that query, because maybe it is succeeding because of the first condition

Comment: I know and fot that reason wrote "but not properly of course"

Comment: I am not saying that the query does not work for your final goal, what I am saying is that it does not work for debugging if there is a problem with your password field

Comment: Can you provide your constructor code as well as FrontEnd Code?